# Node promises not pushing consecutive, nested responses to the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am using AWS Node SDK to for the following tasks -

1. Get Regions
2. Get cluster ARN's per region
3. Get filtered list of ECS clusters.
4. Get services for filtered cluster

The part where I am coming unstuck is step 4, listing the services for each cluster. Essentially a call to list services per cluster, can only return 10 items per response, therefore the function is called recursively to see if another page token exits. Each response is pushed to an array. Then there is a final Promise.all that prints out all the responses. The issue is that only the initial calls are captured, and not any of the recursive calls for next token. Any help would be much appreciated :)

```
function getLiveCluster() {

  var liveClusterName = 'xx1-app-ecs'

  // Filter out the required clusters
  clustersAry.forEach(function(cluster) {
    if (cluster && cluster.clusterArns && cluster.clusterArns.length > 0) {
      cluster.clusterArns.forEach(function(clusterArns) {
        if (clusterArns.indexOf(liveClusterName) > -1) {

          var serviceParams = {
            cluster: clusterArns,
            maxResults: 10,
            nextToken: ''
          };

          ecsRegionParams.region = cluster.RegionName;
          ecs = new aws.ECS(ecsRegionParams);
          getClusterServices(serviceParams)
        }
      });
    }
  });

  Promise.all(promiseAry2).then(() => {
    console.log('All services <<<<<<<<<<<<\n', serviceAry)
  });
}

function getClusterServices(serviceParams) {

  promiseAry2.push(ecs.listServices(serviceParams).promise().then(function(data) {

    serviceAry.push({
      cluster: serviceParams.cluster,
      service: data.serviceArns
    });

    if (data.nextToken) {
      serviceParams.nextToken = data.nextToken;
      getClusterServices(serviceParams)
    }
  }).catch((err) => {}));
}
```

## EDIT 1

After debugging the Promise.all array, there are promises still pending as see here -

```
"> All promiseAry2 <<<<<<<<<<<<
 [ Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { undefined },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]"
```

Any ideas how to ensure that promises complete?

## Answer 1 Response

Thank you - that is a class piece of code and works well with one tiny tweek. The region for ECS needed to be reset as seen here -

```
// Reset ECS to current cluster region
ecsRegionParams.region = cluster.RegionName;

// Store the request for this cluster as a promise
promiseAry.push(
    getClusterServices(
        new aws.ECS(ecsRegionParams),
        serviceParams
    )
)
```

The new output passes back the data in separate objects as seen here -

```
All arrayOfarraysOfServices <<<<<<<<<<<<
[ [ { cluster: 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-1',
service: 
[ 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-1',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-2',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-3',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-4',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-5',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-6',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-7',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-8',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-9',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-10' ] },
{ cluster: 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-1',
service: 
[ 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-11',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-12' ] } ],
[ { cluster: 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-2',
service: 
[ 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-1',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-2',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-3',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-4',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-5',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-6',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-7',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-8',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-9',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-10' ] },
{ cluster: 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-2',
service: 
[ 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-11',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-12' ] } ],
[ { cluster: 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-3',
service: 
[ 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-1',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-2',
'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:service/service-3' ] } ],
[ { cluster: 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-4',
service: [] } ],
[ { cluster: 'arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-5',
service: [] } ]]
```

What I would like to do next is filter the pushes so that if the cluster arn already exists, then the data concatenates to the existing entry.

E.G Cluster arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:0123456789:cluster/xx1-app-ecs-ECSCluster-1 has 12 services, rather than having 2 objects, it would have 1 with the 12 services.

Is it sensible to do this within the function getClusterServices, or should this be done once all the promises are completed, in the Promise.all ?

## Edit 2

Here is one solution to morph the array of arrays back into a singular array, find duplicates, appending duplicate cluster services to current cluster services, then delete duplicate...producing the final paginated cluster service array.

```
Promise.all(promiseAry).then((arrayOfarraysOfServices) => {

    // Consolidate data into singular array
    var singularAry = [];

    // Recursively print array of unknown dimensions
    function morphToSingularArray(arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
                morphToSingularArray(arr[i]);
            } else {
                singularAry.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return singularAry;
    }

    var listAry = morphToSingularArray(arrayOfarraysOfServices);

    // Merge services for duplicate clusters
    // First cluster in array
    for (var i = 0; i < listAry.length; ++i) {
        // Second cluster in array
        for (var j = i + 1; j < listAry.length; ++j) {
            // Matching
            if (listAry[i].cluster === listAry[j].cluster) {
                // Does service object exist
                if (listAry[j].service && listAry[j].service.length > 0) {
                    var serviceAry = listAry[j].service;
                    // Iterate over second cluster services, appending to first cluster services
                    for (var x = 0; x < serviceAry.length; ++x) {
                        listAry[i].service.push(serviceAry[x]);
                    }
                }
                // Delete second cluster after appending
                listAry.splice(j--, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log('Paginated data array\n', listAry)

}).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Can map be used as a cleaner method to the above triplicate array solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your issue, you are passing promises into an array of promises and then you have each of those promises itself potentially push more promises into the same array after the array is already passed into `Promise.all`.

Creating promises in callbacks like this while maintaining all you data globally is a known [anti-pattern with promises](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).

Promises resolve to a value and can be chained, which means we can usually propagate their results through them rather than having global data.

Seems to me that you want to, for each element in `clustersAry`, obtain its services (if they exist), and for each of those services get their services and so on, recursively.

You should have `getClusterServices` itself return a promise that will resolve into an array of services, collected through recursive levels.

Here's one approach based on the comments above:

```
function getLiveCluster() {

  const liveClusterName = 'xx1-app-ecs'

  // Filter out the required clusters
  clustersAry.forEach(cluster => {
    if (cluster && cluster.clusterArns && cluster.clusterArns.length > 0) {
      cluster.clusterArns.forEach(clusterArns => {
        if (clusterArns.indexOf(liveClusterName) > -1) {
          const serviceParams = {
            cluster: clusterArns,
            maxResults: 10,
            nextToken: ''
          };

          // store the request for this cluster as a promise
          promiseAry.push(
            getClusterServices(
              new aws.ECS(cluster.RegionName),
              serviceParams
            )
          )
        }
      });
    }
  });

  Promise.all(promiseAry).then((arrayOfarraysOfServices) => {
    console.log('All services <<<<<<<<<<<<\n', arrayOfarraysOfServices)
  });
}

function getClusterServices(ecs, serviceParams, clusterServiceAry = []) {
  // return a promise here that resolves 
  // with an array of services for the given serviceParams
  // once all recursive service requests are finished
  return ecs
    .listServices(serviceParams)
    .promise()
    .then(data => {
      clusterServiceAry.push({
        cluster: serviceParams.cluster,
        service: data.serviceArns
      });

      return !data.nextToken
        ? clusterServiceAry  // nextToken is falsy, we are finished, resolve with the service array
        : getClusterServices(
            ecs,
            // update the token by creating a new object
            // rather than mutating the existing one
            Object.assign(
              {},
              serviceParams,
              {
                nextToken: data.nextToken
              }
            ),
            // pass the cluster service array so we can accumulate
            // the services
            clusterServiceAry
          )
      })
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that is a class piece of code and works with one tiny tweek.

Comment: @sweeny_here glad to help mate, feel free to edit my answer and add that tiny tweek if you want.

Comment: @new035 - if you're ever in London, I'd like to buy you a pint, or you've a pad to stay in :-)